# How can I run the benchmark tool in Arkham Origins?

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-origins

I'd like to run a benchmark for Batman Arkham Origins to see how changing settings affects frames per second.

I can't see a benchmark option in the menu like previous games, am I missing something?

I should perhaps explain that this is on PC, downloaded from Steam.

Comment: I heard the benchmark was supposed to be included in a future update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a shortcut to the game executable, and then right-click on the shortcut. Choose properties, then at the end of Target text field, after BatmanOrigins.exe" add `benchmark`  Ensure there's a space before benchmark.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. This image helped to clarify what you meant. http://cdn.overclock.net/4/4b/4b8bf763_Untitled.jpeg